# Nested Insert Into Errors

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I've created this Insert Into SQL query, it takes information from the table lessons where the text box containing the lesson ID matches with any of the lessons. I have tested this Query works as it returns the correct values to a datagrid view in.

The second part of the query is supposed to get the student ID and Student Name from the text box that the user has input information. Then transfer this into the Less/Stud table.

This table has a the following Columns

```
Lesson Name     Lesson ID        Student ID        Student Name      Optional?
```

I do not need to worry about the Optional column as that is a check box not needed yet, below is the current query that doesnt work. It returns the following errors:

```
Incorrect Syntax near '/'
Incorrect Syntax near 'Test Student Name'
```

The second error within the ' ' always contains the information from the student name text box.

```
INSERT INTO Less/Stud ([LessonName],[Lesson ID],[Student ID],[Student Name]) 
    SELECT LessonName, LessonID 
    FROM Lessons
    WHERE ClassID ='" + txtClassID.Text + "' 
    AND (SELECT [Student ID], [StudentName] 
    '" + txtStuId.Text + "', '" + txtName.Text + "' "
```

Comment: Pls paste the exact query you are trying to execute...

Comment: You are inserting 4 columns but only 2 values. and 'Less/Stud' is your table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all four columns being inserted in the outer `select`:

```
INSERT INTO Less/Stud ([LessonName],[Lesson ID],[Student ID],[Student Name]) 
    SELECT LessonName, LessonID, '" + txtStuId.Text + "', '" + txtName.Text + "' "
    FROM Lessons
    WHERE ClassID ='" + txtClassID.Text + "'
```

Comment: This Worked! 
Thank you very much I think I was making it a bit harder for myself than it needed to be.

Only edit thing I needed to edit from your code was [Less/Stud] needed square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Is "Less/Stud" your table name? I would suggest putting that in quotes, because the / seems to be confusing the database.

The WHERE clause also seems to be incomplete. A subselection is being started, but never completed.

You should also only put the fields you actually want to insert data into in the first line. Since you only provide 2 values in the SELECT clause, you can not define 4 fields to insert into.

EDIT: It turns out you want to insert values from a textbox into the Student ID and Student Name fields, based on your clarification. I have altered my suggested query to reflect this. I have not been able to test this, so I might have some mismatching quotes here and there, but I think it should be something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO [Less/Stud] ([LessonName],[Lesson ID],[Student ID],[StudentName]) 
SELECT LessonName
, LessonID
,  '" + txtStuId.Text + "'
, '" + txtName.Text + "' 
FROM Lessons
WHERE ClassID ='" + txtClassID.Text + "' "
```

You might want to consider using the String.Format() method to put the textbox values into the SQL string though. I personally think the string would be more readable that way. It would look like this:

```
var yourQuery = String.Format(
            "INSERT INTO [Less/Stud] ([LessonName],[Lesson ID],[Student ID],[StudentName]) SELECT LessonName, LessonID, '{0}', '{1}' FROM Lessons WHERE ClassID ='{2}' "
            , txtStuId.Text
            , txtName.Text
            , txtClassId.Text
            );
```

Breaking up the SQL statement itself into multiple lines might also be a good idea, especially for even longer and/or more complicated statements.

Comment: Yes that is my table i've changed it to [Less/Stud]

The part that doesnt work is supposed to select the values within the text boxes txtStuID and txtName then add them into the column Student ID and Student Name a long with the lesson information.
Im unsure if SELECT is the best way to do this or INSERT would be better?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your query.

1. If your table is `Less/Stud` then you must call the table name with square brackets like `[Less/Stud]`
2. Your `Insert` query have 4 columns but your `SELECT` query have only 2 columns. Thats also must be changed.

And the most important one, your query is prone to SQL injection. Try to use [parameterized](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx) query.

Comment: I've changed the table name into square brackets thank you.

My insert query has four columns as I also want to INSERT the student ID and student Name into Less/Stud but this information needs to come from the two text boxes. 
I don't know if need a nested INSERT query to do this or If I can run the two select queries together even if they are getting information from two places?